# .each() loop works fine locally but once uploaded to server stops working

Tags: jquery, xml, loops, each

I'm using jQuery to dynamically populate a select element. The content of the option tags is returned from an xml document (the xml file itself is in fact a php file but it is generated as  xml). The ajax function seems to work as far as I can see but the part that doesn't is the $.each loop which traverses through the xml. Whats really driving me mad is that it all works perfectly when run locally on MAMP, but once put online it fails to work. The file structure is exactly the same online as it is locally.

Here is the xml:

```
<classes>
    <name>MM1</name>
    <name>MM2</name>
    <name>MM3</name>
    <name>MM4</name>
    <name>PR1</name>
    <name>PR2</name>
    <name>PR3</name>
    <name>PR4</name>
</classes>
```

Here is the jQuery:

```
var preview_div_top = $('<div class = "preview_div_top"/>');
var form = $('<form action = ""/>');

$.ajax(
{
    type: "GET",
    async: false,
    url: "xml/get_classes.php",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml)
    {
        var dropdown = '<select class = "class_list">';

        $(xml).find('name').each(function()
        {                       
            var theClass = $(this).text();
            dropdown += '<option value = "' + theClass + '">' + theClass + '</option>';
        });

        dropdown += '</select>';
        $(form).append(dropdown);
        $(form).append('<input type = "submit" class = "get_schedule_btn">');
    } // end success function           
}); // end AJAX

preview_div_top.append(form);
$('.preview .button').after(preview_div_top);
```

It only stopped working when I put it on a real server. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Any feedback from browser console?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What exactly is not working?

Comment: Did you try accessing the PHP URL to see if you get the correct XML as output?

Answer (score -1):

You need to make sure that the JavaScript includes are well linked. Use tools like Chrome Debugger Net Panel or Firebug extension in Firefox.

Comment: Ok I was using Chrome's console to debug and after checking firebug in firefox it showed up the ajax calls as I made them, which returned the error: on the php - xml output, I had the wrong database details. Was using root & root. I feel quite stupid now having put this up, I'm just going to use firebug every time now, thanks for the help guys.